# Losing type safety when using generics

Tags: java, generics, types

I have an utility class (ListUtils) to deep copy lists. The important method in that class is copy, defined as follows:

```
public static <T  extends ICopy> List<T> copy(List<T> xs) {
    LinkedList<T> newList = new LinkedList<>() ;
    for(T x : xs) {
        newList.add(x.<T> copy()) ;
    }
    return xs;
}
```

The ICopy interface, in turn, is given by:

```
public interface ICopy {
    <T extends ICopy> T copy() ;
}
```

Then, to force every AST node to implement ICopy, the IAstNode is defined as follows:

```
public interface IAstNode extends ICopy {

    ImmutableList<? extends IAstNode> getChildren() ;

    int getStartLine() ;
    int getEndLine() ;

    IAstNode copy() ;
}
```

At this point, I lose type safety, as the Java compiler indicates that I should write copy with a suppress warning annotations?

Any insights of what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ICopy` interface, you have made the method `copy` generic, not the interface itself.  This means that any implementing method must also be generic, with the same bounds, return type, and signature, to avoid a compiler error and a compiler warning.  You would need in `IAstNode`:

```
<T extends ICopy> T copy();
```

This holds true even if you intended `T` to be `IAstNode` here.  You get an unchecked conversion warning with your current code because `T` could be `IAstNode`.  The unchecked conversion warning is the sign that you've lost type safety with your code, even if the compiler will let you compile the code.

What you can do to preserve type safety is to move the declaration of the generic type parameter from the `copy` method to the interface `ICopy` itself.

```
public interface ICopy<T extends ICopy<T>> {
    T copy();
}
```

Then any subinterface (or implementing class) can supply a type argument, or it declare its own type parameter, to be used in extending or implementing the interface.

Here's what `IAstNode` looks like now.  It declares its own type parameter with its own bounds, that fits the bounds imposed by `ICopy`.  It uses it as a type argument when extending `ICopy`.  The `copy` method signature is simpler now.

I gave the type parameter `T` to the `ImmutableList` type for `getChildren`; it makes the most sense in this context.

```
public interface IAstNode<T extends IAstNode<T>> extends ICopy<T> {

    ImmutableList<T> getChildren() ;

    int getStartLine() ;
    int getEndLine() ;

    T copy();
}
```

Any class that wants to specify what `T` actually is can do so:

```
public class MyAstNode implements IAstNode<MyAstNode>
```

The `copy` method would return a `MyAstNode`, and `getChildren` would return an `ImmutableList<MyAstNode>`.

Comment: "This means that any implementing method must also be generic, with the same bounds, return type, and signature, to avoid a compiler error and a compiler warning. ". Perfect explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: You are using `ICopy` as a raw type in the bound of the type parameter of `ICopy`, so this code is itself unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type `T` on interface level

```
public interface ICopy<T extends ICopy>  {
    T copy() ;
}
```

Your copy method should be amended to

```
public <T extends ICopy<T>> List<T> copy(List<T> xs) {
    LinkedList<T> newList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (T x : xs) {
        newList.add(x.copy());
    }
    return xs;
}
```

Comment: Ok, let us go further in that direction.

Suppose that I now implement a concrete AST class, e.g, X. I would have something like:

       public class X implements IAstNode<X> {
             ...
       }

That looks weird. Moreover, can you explain your solution?

Comment: @leco Then you have to implement `public IAstNode copy()` as you have defined it in `IAstNode`. If this is not what you want to do, you should explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: You are using `ICopy` as a raw type in the bound of the type parameter of `ICopy`, so this code is itself unsafe.

Comment: @newacct Could you please explain why it's unsafe? Does it not ensure that `T copy()` returns a class of named type `T` which implements `ICopy`?

Comment: @SubOptimal: Raw types should never be used in new code. If you care about the parameter of `ICopy` that `T` extends, (e.g. `T extends ICopy<T>` if you want `T` to extend `ICopy` with a parameter of `T` again). If you don't care, then it should be `T extends ICopy<?>`, but in that case you should think about whether you even need a bound in the first place.